# Android studio - Google Analytics V4?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am using from this sample [HERE](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/) but it didn't work for me and I don't see any result in google analytics.

I created an Google Analytics Account 2 days ago, and I inserted the trackingId in my app  on 8 April - May 2016.
What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the official Google Analytics Android SDK v4 docs here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/